# How to map an Entity Framework model that has a list property using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Database first approach to map my tables to entity models. Currently I have two tables, Orders and Products:

```
Orders: Id, DateCreated

Products: Id, Name, OrderId
```

As you can see it's a one to many relationship. And I would like to create a view using these two tables and map it to an entity called `Order` and `Products`:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
    public IList<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I know how to map a single property, but have no idea how I would approach it for a list property. Any ideas?

Please note that the tables are slightly more complicated and I HAVE TO use views to map these entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of guides on it around the web.
[one of them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) is @ msdn site

Replace IList with ICollection and you should be good with that.

Comment: that was very helpful. THANKS!